# How can i exclude a tuple when webscraping?

Tags: python, beautifulsoup

When i run this code i get a list with all the right information. So that works, but i also get the words form the exlude list.

Is there any way i can remove all the words in the exclusive list from the output?

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
url = 'https://www.finn.no/bap/forsale/search.html?category=0.93&product_category=2.93.3904.69&sub_category=1.93.3904'
page = requests.get(url)
soup = BeautifulSoup(page.content, 'html.parser')
exclude = ('UTLEIE', 'Utleie', 'utleie', 'NIKON', 'Nikon', 'nikon' 'Leica', 'LEICA', 'leica', 'sony', 'SONY', 'Sony', 'Pentax', 'PENTAX', 'pentax', 'RF', 'iphone', 'android', 'Magic', 'MAGIC', 'magic')


def check_status(func):
    def verify(*args, **kwargs):
        if page.status_code != 200:
            return f'Error code: {page.status_code}'
        return func(*args, **kwargs)
    return verify

@check_status
def scrape_website():
    for i in soup.find_all('article',  {'class': 'ads__unit'}):
        for j in i.find('a', {'class': 'ads__unit__link'}):
            if any(s not in j.strip().lower() for s in exclude):
                print(j.strip())
scrape_website()
#---------------------------------------------------------------------------#
[Running] python -u "h:\webscrapfinn\tempCodeRunnerFile.py"
Canon efs 17-55 mm
Canon EF 50mm f/1.2L USM
Linser til mobiltelefon
Ricoh 50 mm f2 for Pentax speireflex, og Pentax til Sony E converter
nikon 14-24mm
TIL UTLEIE - Sigma 50mm 1.4 Art
Olympus M.Zuiko ED 14-150mm f/4-5.6
Sony 16-35mm F4
TIL UTLEIE - Canon 16-35mm F4 IS
Nikon 20mm 1.8
Fujinon 55-200mm
```

Comment: When you say exclude, you mean you don't want those line items in the output, right?

Comment: yes, thats what i mean, sry for bad english

Comment: No problem! I've answered it for you below! Let me know if that's what you wanted.

Answer (score 1):

You wrote:

```
if any(s not in j.strip().lower() for s in exclude):
    print(j.strip())
```

This is saying "if any of my blacklisted words are not in the current tag, print the tag". By that logic, the only way the tag would not print is if all blacklisted words appeared in the tag.

I would maybe write it like this instead:

```
if any(s in j.strip().lower() for s in exclude):
    continue
print(j.strip())
```

Note: The print-statement is not in the if-statement, but still in the inner for-loop. This way, as soon as any single one of your blacklisted words appears in the current tag, you skip the current tag and move onto the next one.

Comment: does't look like it worked, no error tho but still the same result

Answer (score 1):

EDIT : So 'j' is a string of words coming from the webscraper module, hence you need to convert them into a list of words in order to check whether any of the word belongs to the exclude list or not.

You also need to 'lower' all the words in the exclude list before comparison.
Make that a list and convert them to lowercase words from a list.

Converting both these lists into sets, gives you the advantage of using the set operations for comparison.

Do an intersection of them both and check if there's anything common. If there isn't any, print it.

Just remove the line :

```
if any(s not in j.strip().lower() for s in exclude):
```

and use :

```
if not set(word.strip().lower().split()) & set(exclude):
```

Basically in code :

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
import requests
url = 'https://www.finn.no/bap/forsale/search.html?category=0.93&product_category=2.93.3904.69&sub_category=1.93.3904'
page = requests.get(url)
soup = BeautifulSoup(page.content, 'html.parser')
exclude = ['UTLEIE', 'Utleie', 'utleie', 'NIKON', 'Nikon', 'nikon' 'Leica', 'LEICA', 'leica', 'sony', 'SONY', 'Sony', 'Pentax', 'PENTAX', 'pentax', 'RF', 'iphone', 'android', 'Magic', 'MAGIC', 'magic']

exclude = [x.lower() for x in exclude]


def check_status(func):
    def verify(*args, **kwargs):
        if page.status_code != 200:
            return f'Error code: {page.status_code}'
        return func(*args, **kwargs)
    return verify

@check_status
def scrape_website():
    for i in soup.find_all('article',  {'class': 'ads__unit'}):
        for word in i.find('a', {'class': 'ads__unit__link'}):
            if not set(word.strip().lower().split()) & set(exclude):
                print(word.strip())
scrape_website()
```

Comment: does't look like it worked, no error tho but still the same result

Comment: After checking the code, I made the required modifications. This should work now.